# Method Overloading Of >> Binary Operator To Print A String

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want the StringClass class with overloading the >> binary operator like as follows:

```
StringClass teststring; 
teststring = "test"; 
printf("%s", teststring >> 5);
```

and there will be 
testtesttesttesttest
printed (five times.)

Comment: If you have printf already, why need to overload >>? also printf%s doesn't work with StringClass

Comment: At least co-opt the multiplication operator, which has roughly the same semantics... `>>` has a very different meaning, and very specific meaning when talking about strings and IO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your needs. I discourage this things, but here it is.

And yeah, bad static variable. Bad practices. Who cares.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std ;

const char* operator >> (const string &str, const int n) {
    static string ret_string ;
    ret_string.clear() ;
    for (int i=0 ; i<n ; i++) {
        ret_string += str ;
    }
    return ret_string.c_str() ;
}

int main() {
    string str="test" ;
    printf("%s", str>>5) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

As you can see, just define `>>` operator to return whatever you want.
Warning about the static variable, no reentrant, blah,blah,blah :)
Hope helps.

If you wish, you can enclose the operator definition inside you class (if it is not for `string` class).

** thanks P0W for initial code structure.

Answer (score 0):

Why `printf` use ?

I can think of this :-

```
void operator >> (const std::string &str,const int n)
{
  for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
   cout<<str;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str="TEST";
    str>>5;
}
```

Comment: I know mixing C++ streams with Cstdio functions is not advised but i was just curious as how to implement it using printf. It would be great if you can help me with that.
Thanks

Comment: @P0W Which is undefined behavior.  You're passing an invalid pointer to `printf`.

Comment: @JamesKanze ahh yeah, I'll revert back to original one